# How can I store data into array of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$scope.arrSportData = data.sportdata;

        angular.forEach($scope.arrSportData, function(value, key){
             $scope.associatedSportplayer = value;
         console.log($scope.associatedSportplayer);

        //getting reponse

        /*
        Object { id: "1", user_id: "2", sport_id: "1", position_id: "1"}
        Object { id: "2", user_id: "2", sport_id: "2", position_id: "6"}
        Object { id: "3", user_id: "2", sport_id: "3", position_id: "12"}
        Object { id: "4", user_id: "2", sport_id: "5", position_id: "20"}
        */  

        });
```

I would like to pick the sport_id into array i.e array [1,2,3,5]

Please guide thanks in advance

Comment: angularJS donot have special Array, they are just object of JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var datas = [{
  id: "1",
  user_id: "2",
  sport_id: "1",
  position_id: "1"
}, {
  id: "2",
  user_id: "2",
  sport_id: "2",
  position_id: "6"
}, {
  id: "3",
  user_id: "2",
  sport_id: "3",
  position_id: "12"
}, {
  id: "4",
  user_id: "2",
  sport_id: "5",
  position_id: "20"
}];

var sport_ids = datas.map(function(data) {
  return Number(data.sport_id)
});

alert(sport_ids);
```

So, you can pretty much make use of javascript's `map` function to pipe an array of data in one format and convert it into another array with extracted data from original array.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: getting response in this format Array [ "1", "2", "3", "5" ] want Array [ 1, 2, 3, 5 ] without quote

Comment: Updated the answer. You can parse string to int using `Number(string_representation)`

Answer (score 0):

You can push to a empty array at the `$scope`:

```
$scope.arrSportData = data.sportdata;
$scope.newArr = [];

angular.forEach($scope.arrSportData, function(value, key){
     $scope.associatedSportplayer = value;
     $scope.newArr.push($scope.associatedSportplayer.sport_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to have sport_id into an array.

```
 var tempArr = []; 
   angular.forEach($scope.arrSportData, function(value, key){
       tempArr.push(value.sport_id);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.arrSportData = [ { id: "1", user_id: "2", sport_id: "1", position_id: "1"},{ id: "2", user_id: "2", sport_id: "2", position_id: "6"},{ id: "3", user_id: "2", sport_id: "3", position_id: "12"},{ id: "4", user_id: "2", sport_id: "5", position_id: "20"}];
  $scope.sportId = [];
angular.forEach($scope.arrSportData, function(value, key){
             $scope.associatedSportplayer = value;
         $scope.sportId.push($scope.associatedSportplayer.sport_id);
  
  });
  console.log($scope.sportId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where you need it, but this is the general idea...

```
$scope.arrSportData = data.sportdata;
$scope.arrSportID = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.arrSportData, function(value, key){
        $scope.arrSportID.push(value.id);
    }

console.log($scope.arrSportID);
```

Comment: thanks @user1034092 I was doing the same thing but don't know what was going wrong. nevertheless thanks a ton

Comment: getting response in this format Array [ "1", "2", "3", "5" ] want Array [ 1, 2, 3, 5 ] without quote

Comment: Do you need to save them (in the JSON object) with quotes?
Is there a reason that in datas its {id:"1"} and not {id:1}?

Answer (score -1):

You need to store the values in an object and then push it to array.

```
$scope.item = {};  
  $scope.addItem = function() {   
      var newItem ={};   
      newItem.name= $scope.item.name;   
      newItem.title=$scope.item.title; 

   $scope.contact.items.push(newItem); 
   console.log( $scope.contact.items); 
  }
```